# Determine the position and value of peak

Tags: matlab, optimization, max

I have a graph with five major peaks. I'd like to find the position and value of the first peak (the one furthest to the right). I have more than 100 different plots of this and the peak grows and shrinks in size in the various plots, and will need to use a for loop. I'm just stuck on determining the x and y values to a large number of significant figures using Matlab code.

Here's one of the many plots:
[image: http://img690.imageshack.us/img690/6467/hiok.jpg]

Comment: It seems from your image that there is a lot of 'high frequency noise' of small sub-peaks, which makes it difficult to find the 'first peak from the right'. Did you try some sort of low-pass filtering? If you can make some smooth curve that crosses some given threshold exactly once up and once down for the rightmost peak, it is a lot easier ...

Comment: Is it always the first peak from the right (i.e, the last peak)? Or do you want the largest peak? Are these true peaks, or as @BasSwinckels suggests, are there lots little noisy subpeaks within each major peak when you zoom in?

Comment: Why are you hung up on "determining the x and y values to a large number of significant figures using Matlab code"? Can you show what you have tried and why this is a problem?

Answer (score 2):

If you know for sure you're always gonna have 5 peaks I think the FileExchange function `extrema` will be very helpful, see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12275).

This will return you the maxima (and minima if needed) in descending order, so the first elements of output `zmax` and `imax` are respectively the maximal value and its index, their second elements are the second maximum value and its index and so on.

In the case if the peak you need is always the smallest of the five you'll just need `zmax(5)` and `imax(5)` to determine the 5th biggest maximum.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to Signal Processing Toolbox, [`findpeaks`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/signal/ref/findpeaks.html) is the function you are looking for. It can be invoked using different options including number of peaks, which can be helpful when that information is available.